# Empty value of input text in loop - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user click on a checkbox bound to an item, it displays elements quantity input box and price input box  where users type in quantity and price on my `panel_checkout`.

When user select first item `Printers` and enters the `quantity and price`
it calculates my total accurately.

When user selects next item `Washing Gears`, and type a quantity number `eg:2`, it multiplies the `2 by the price of the printer`. Same applies when i type a price `eg: 4`, it multiplies `the 4 by the quantity of the printer`.

This shows the input values for quantity and price do not reset when i click on a new item.  How do i get this solved? Thanks for your help.

```js
var order_container;
var quantity;
var price;
var sum;
    
function order(products) { 
  $('.panel_checkout').append('<div class="order_container"><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" id="qty" name="quantity[]" required/><input type="text" class="form-control item_price" id="price" name="price[]" required/><p class="total">USD<span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p></div>' )
}
 $('.checkout_panel').on('keyup','.quantity',function() {
  order_container = $(this).closest('div');
  quantity = Number($(this).val());  
  price = document.getElementById('price').value
  order_container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
  sum = 0;  
  $(".line-total").each(function(){
    sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
  })
})
 $('.checkout_panel').on('keyup','.item_price',function() {
  order_container = $(this).closest('div');   
  price = Number($(this).val()); 
  quantity = document.getElementById('qty').value   
  order_container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
  sum = 0;
  points = 0;
  $(".line-total").each(function(){
    sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
  })  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="return order(this)" />
<div class="panel_checkout"></div>
```

Comment: Please create an example of your problem, since it hard to debug your code without the HTML itself. Also, It would help if you formatted the jQuery code so it was more readable.

Comment: Press `Edit` > In edit window > Press `{}` to add a Code Snippet > Insert your code > Add `jQuery 2.1.1` > Test `Run` your code, and then save the snippet into your answer. This will allow us to run your code on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Also add necessary commas into your code and make sure your code is atleast functional. [`How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add your HTMl and fix your JS, it's completely broken, braces are all over the place. Organize your question please.

Comment: Are you generating new inputs? Do they have unique `ids`? If they don't, your call for `price = document.getElementById('price').value` will always return the first.

Comment: @Jack, yes my products have unique ids using this `var ad = JSON.parse(products.dataset.products)` as in my code. I am able to get the unique ids of every product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is completely broken. See the code snippet below:

```js
var sum = 0;

function order() {
  $( '.panel_checkout' ).append( '<div class="order_container"><input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" oninput="qt( this )" placeholder="Quantity" required/><input type="number" class="form-control item_price" name="price[]" oninput="pr( this )" placeholder="Price" required/> <span class="line-total" name="total"></span> USD</div>' )
}

function qt( el ) {
  var order_container, quantity, price;

  order_container = $( el ).closest( 'div' );
  quantity = Number( $( el ).val() );
  price = order_container.find( '.item_price' ).val();
  order_container.find( '.line-total' ).text( quantity * price );
  sum = 0;

  $( '.line-total' ).each( function() {
    sum = sum + Number( $( this ).text() )
  } )

  $( '.sum' ).text( sum )
}

function pr( el ) {
  var order_container, quantity, price;

  order_container = $( el ).closest( 'div' );
  price = Number( $( el ).val() );
  quantity = order_container.find( '.quantity' ).val();
  order_container.find( '.line-total' ).text( quantity * price );
  sum = 0;

  $( '.line-total' ).each( function() {
    sum = sum + Number( $( this ).text() )
  } )

  $( '.sum' ).text( sum )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="order()"/>
<p>
  <div class="panel_checkout"></div>
</p>
<hr/>
<p>Total: <span class="sum">0</span> USD</p>
```